# need database model for online game

Tags: mysql, sql, database, relational-database

I need a database model for an online game:

The game should save the characters which have more or less this type of character file:

http://pastebin.com/tsWdaxte

Every player has:
-a username, password and a bunch of ints/strings
-a container "inventory" which holds "items(id & amount)" in a certain slot
-a container "bank" which also holds items
-a container "equipment" which also holds items
-a friendslist which holds longs (64 bit integers which can be converted to usernames)
-skills which are specified with an "id"(int) and "experience"(int)

My current idea was to use the following tables:
-players
-inventory
-bank
-equipment
-friends
-skills

all containers would look something like
id | amount | slot | owner_id

every player should have its own "id" which would be auto-incremented

but I'm not exactly sure how the primary keys & foreign keys system works in MySQL and I'd prefer to have some professional help instead of trying to figure out things on my own

Comment: We're not gonna code it for you. Make some database code, test it yourself, and when/if you run into problems, post a VERY SPECIFIC question here, or post your whole DB over on CodeReview.SE.

Comment: This is way too broad. There's a difference between asking for help on a specific issue (like how can I make these foreign keys work) versus asking for a completed back-end design. Professional help should not be sought on StackOverflow. Such things tend to be overly-broad and no single answer.

Answer (score 0):

You definitely could use the layout you suggested with the tables players, inventory, bank (although I'd put inventory and bank into one and have a boolean "isbanked" or w/e), equipment, friends, and skills. Although I think you could also throw all of them except skills into the players table and just split the string using String.split(","); in java. Look up auto increment primary keys when creating a table; it does it all for you pretty much.